# Can a person see himself being taken into the grave?

Tags: source-identification, death

I got a WhatsApp message about what a person sees during death and it was written there that a dead man does not realize that he is dead initially. He feels himself dreaming of death, he sees himself weeping, bathed, tied and descended into the Grave. He still feels dreaming when he is hoarded by the ground. He then screams but nobody hears his shout. Sometimes later, when everyone is dispersed and he is left alone under the ground, Allah restores his soul. Are all these I have mentioned true?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. Did the message mention any sources or references?

Comment: See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQ4UTqFkvCM

Comment: No there was nothing mentioned. Thanks for the link. Jazak Allah Khair

Answer (score -3):

first off, thats one weird WhatsApp message bro. and yes all of this is true from what i know of, except that the SOUL sees this stuff not the actual body. and when you are dead and in the grave, your soul stays there and gets questioned after a little (whos your prophet, whos your God, whats your religon) by the 2 angels of death. thennnnnn your soul gets dealt with and only returns on the day of judgement (unless u were so good ur already in heaven)

i am not a scholar, dont take what ive said to heart, im a sunni muslim and that is what i have heard from reading multiple books by sunni scholars.